# Requirejs and ajax - loading a bundle/component of .js .html .css dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, requirejs

Below is a piece of code (very simplified) that I tore out of a small webshop project of mine.

Now I am starting a larger project where I will need dependency management. I have looked into require.js and I was wondering if it supports an equivalent way of doing this, or if I can use my approach alongside requirejs.

The reason why I want this is mainly that I like this way of code organisation - to have files belonging together in the same folder (along with a unittest file f.i.). Also to load scripts only when they are needed.

```
function loadComponent(componentName, $container) {
    var path = sourcePath(componentName),
        component;

    $.when( $.get(path + '.html'), 
            $.get(path + '.css'), 
            $.get(path + '.js')
            )
    .done(function(htmlResponse, cssResponse, jsResponse){
        $("head").append("<style>" + cssResponse[0] + "</style>");
        $("head").append("<script>" + jsResponse[0] + "</script>");
        $container.html(htmlResponse[0]);

        component = new window[componentName](params);
        component.init();
    });
}
```

A use-case could be to have this code:

```
$("nav li").each(function(){
    var $item = $(this);

    $item.on("click", function() {
        $("article").loadComponent($item.attr("name"));
    });
});
```

where you'd have an html like:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="home" name="Home">Home</li>
        <li id="about" name="About">About</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<article></article>
```

and a component called 'Home':

```
var Home = function() {

    return {
        init : function(){
            console.log("Home component, init is called");
        }
    };      
};
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a project I have been playing with on GitHub: [require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy)

It allows for lazy loading of RequireJS modules, much like your method with promises, e.g.:

```
define(["lazy!module1"], function(lazyModule1) {
    ...
    lazyModule1.get().done(function(realModule1) {
        // do stuff with the real module1
    });
    ...
});
```

The advantage of require-lazy is that it can automatically split the lazy-loaded modules out of the main bundle, when using r.js, plus cache breaking.

There is a [grunt](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy-grunt) and [bower](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy-bower) component too. There is not much documentation, but do take a look at the examples folder (start with simple), I believe they are explanatory enough.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely have a look!